# Functions with <>s and listing partial classes under a single file?

Tags: c#

What are functions with <> called? I mean, I usually see them in defining lists like List<> SortedList<> etc. And they get value types into their parameters (as I've seen). (`List<bool>` etc.). Could I create a class that gets value types as parameters like that?

```
CustomClass<bool, int>(32, "asd") test;
```

Other question:
Could I list seperated but partial classes under a single file (like Form's form.designer.cs and form.resx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Other question: no afaik (if you talk about vs solution explorer) but you can put partial classes into single file.

Comment: which one (generics or the partial class thing)?

Comment: Form1.cs
>Form1.designer.cs
>Form1.resx
(partial class thing)

Comment: the solution explorer in vs will not allow that, but you can write a vs add-in which do that :P

Answer (score 0):

In general, have multiple partial classes in the same file. The only limitation is that they are part of the same assembly.

However, the `Form1.designer.cs` and `Form1.resx` files are generated by VS's editing tools. If you try messing around with generated files, they just get generated again. Furthermore, the `.resx` file isn't even C# -- it's XML!